# .Net-core continuous Deployment

Tags: azure, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have set up continuous deployment from a github repository, and the deployment succeds, but when i navigate to the site.azurewebsites.net I get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page. I have aslo set up a .deployment file in my root directory to point to the correct folder that holds the program and project.json file

Here is the deployment script that is run  and the project stucture
[Generate Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fICQm.png)

[DeploymentScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyFW1.png)

The Project structure is

```
    |Core Folder
    |   Project Folder
    |      src
    |        Project1
    |          wwwroot
    |            files
    |          program.cs
    |          project.json
    |          other files...
    |.deployment
 The deployment points to Projectfolder/src/Project1
```

Comment: Have you checked the site's content via FTP to see what got deployed and where? Have you also tried setting up the continuous deployment using the Web App's settings blade in the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to adjust the publish scripts to get it to publish correctly:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "Web"
  }
}
```

Something similar to the above got it to deploy correctly - with the correct deployment script in the root folder.